# Row counting a JOINed column without affecting the returned rows?

Tags: mysql, join, count

It's a bit difficult getting my problem into a short form, so I apologise if the title doesn't make sense.

Anyway, here is the problem:

```
 $query = '
  SELECT issues.*, comments.author AS commentauthor, favorites.userid AS favorited FROM issues
  LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.issue = issues.id AND comments.when_posted = issues.when_updated
  LEFT JOIN favorites ON favorites.ticketid = issues.id AND favorites.userid = \'' . $_SESSION['uid'] . '\'
  ' . $whereclause . '
  ORDER BY issues.when_updated ' . $order;
```

Don't mind the fact that it's PHP as I am **not** asking for PHP help.

The query retrieves a bunch of `issues`, and what I'm wishing to do is obtain the row count of `favorites` that have `favorites.ticketid` matching `issues.id`. My use of `LEFT JOIN favorites` is not to get what I've just mentioned, but instead to obtain whether the client has favourited the issue, thus the part `favorites.userid AS favorited`.

I have tried doing the following: (all at once, I'm putting this in bulleted form for readibility)

- duplicating the existing `LEFT JOIN favorites` and removing the user id check from the duplicate
- adding `, COUNT(favorites.ticketid) AS favoritescount` to the `SELECT` section
- adding `AS favorited` to the original `LEFT JOIN` as well as changing `favorites.userid` to `favorited.userid`

With that attempt, my query ends up returning only one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT issues.*,
       comments.author AS commentauthor,
       favorites.userid AS favorited,
       (
           SELECT COUNT(favorites.id)
           FROM favorites
           WHERE ticketid = issues.id
       ) AS numfavorites
FROM issues
LEFT JOIN comments
    ON comments.issue = issues.id
    AND comments.when_posted = issues.when_updated
LEFT JOIN favorites
    ON favorites.ticketid = issues.id
    AND favorites.userid = ?uid
```

That should work, I'm just using a subquery to get number of favourites